# How do you test a case of Layout Binding in Mockito or any Unit Test (for coverage)?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, android-viewbinding

I am currently looking for a way to test a couple of methods, and I am using Layout Bindings.

```
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
```

After most login, at some point, the code interacts with the binding and it throws a Null Pointer, I debugged a bit and noticed that the spy(k) Fragment's Binding is null, and even if I were to do the same logic inside the activity its binding is null as well.

Any ideas/ advice can provide more source code if necessary.

```
class MockKitoTestJune {

    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() = MockKAnnotations.init(this)

    @Before
    fun init() {
//        mockStatic(PatternsCompat::class.java)

        mockkStatic(Looper::class)
        every { Looper.myLooper() } returns mockk()

        mockkStatic(Log::class)
        every { Log.v(any(), any()) } returns 0
        every { Log.d(any(), any()) } returns 0
        every { Log.i(any(), any()) } returns 0
        every { Log.e(any(), any()) } returns 0

        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)
    }


    @Test
    fun testMockK() {
        //Code that uses the mock here
        val email = "String@gmail.com"
        val password = "String"
        val fullName = "String"

        // given
        val signUpFragment = spyk<SignUpFragment>()

        doReturn(signUpFragment.validateForm(email, password, fullName)).`when`(true)
        doReturn(signUpFragment.validateForm("", password, fullName)).`when`(false)
        doReturn(signUpFragment.validateForm(null, password, fullName)).`when`(false)
        doReturn(signUpFragment.validateForm(email, "", fullName)).`when`(false)
        doReturn(signUpFragment.validateForm(email, password, "")).`when`(false)

        // when checking mocked method
        val goodResult = signUpFragment.validateForm(email, password, fullName)
        val firstResult = signUpFragment.validateForm("", password, fullName)

        // then
        assertThat(goodResult).isTrue()
        assertThat(firstResult).isFalse()
    }
}
```

In the logic when it gets to this -

```
binding.editTextFullName.error = "You need to enter a name"
```

This is part of the Fragment:

```
private var _binding: FragmentSignUpBinding? = null
val binding get() = _binding!!


  override fun onCreateView(
_binding = FragmentSignUpBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

.
.
.
```

Comment: please help answerer posting your code

Comment: @skafle hopefully this is helpful